# How to insert special characters not on a US/UK keyboard?

Tags: osx, keyboard-layout

At work I use a MacMini connected to an italian layout keyboard (please, look at the image) [image]

I've discovered that Emacs doesn't insert the characters `@` and `#` when I use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>ò</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>à</kbd>, respectively.

Any clue?

Comment: Try `C-h k AltGr-ò` to determine what emacs receives. Maybe you can bind that to the required character by `(global-set-key [...] (lambda () (interactive) "@"))`.

Comment: M-ò is undefined 
M-à is undefined

Comment: I don't have experience with Mac OS. Maybe, the solution of matteol is the way to go. If for any reason that is not possible for you my next best guess would be to use `(global-set-key (kbd "M-ò") (lambda () (interactive) "@"))`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a configuration that let you use the left Alt as Meta and the right one to insert special characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the following in my init.el to use the italian layout with Mac OS

```
;; Command key is Meta
(setq ns-command-modifier 'meta)
;; Option (alt) key used for special characters (e.g. []@#{}...)
(setq ns-alternate-modifier nil)
```

If you want to use the left Alt key as Meta and the right one to insert special characters you can set the following

```
;; AltGr used for special characters (e.g. []@#{}...)
(setq ns-right-alternate-modifier nil)
```

leaving the default values for `ns-command-modifier` and `ns-alternate-modifier`.