# I want to type special Spanish characters in Emacs on a MacBook Pro keyboard ... but I have no clue where to start

Tags: osx, input-method, keyboard-layout

I am using Emacs 26.3 with macos Catalina and I would like to type the inverted exclamation point and question mark characters. Can someone point me to a link that will get me started towards understanding how to input special characters not available on my standard MacBook Pro keyboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert special characters not on a US/UK keyboard?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37172/how-to-insert-special-characters-not-on-a-us-uk-keyboard)

Comment: Aside, if you're using unicode (most likely) and you install counsel,  `counsel-unicode-char` will help you finding more exotic chars via completion. Pretty neat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: <kbd>C-u C\ spanish-prefix RET</kbd>. The characters you mentioned can then be typed as

```
~? => ¿
~! => ¡
```

Long answer: read the emacs documentation starting at [Language Environments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Language-Environments.html), plus the description of 'spanish-prefix' in `lisp/leim/quail/latin-pre.el` to see what other characters that method supports, and to see what other input methods are available, such as `catalan-prefix` and `spanish-keyboard`.

Comment: The linked documentation plus the section that follows on Input Methods were very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out this is how you do it: `(setq ns-alternate-modifier nil)`

I was instead using the `insert-chart` bound to `C-x 8` which is very painful

*edit:* *thank you all for the interest xD*

I'm native spanish speaker and I really need to introduce characters like `á`, `é`, `í` etc... otherwise my notes make no sense! I'm also a mac book pro user, trying spacemacs + org-mode for a change. To finish contextualizing my answer, I must clarify that I use my keyboard with the following changes:

- Key `Caps Lock` maps to `Control`
- Key `Control` maps to `Command`
- Key `Option` maps to `Caps Lock`
- Key `Command` maps to `Option`

In this universe, I order to produce an `á` symbol I press Key `Command-e a`. I find this very comfortable. As soon as I started taking notes in org-mode I realized I couldn't type Key `Command-e`, didn't understand why.

I've found the solution and now I have a theory that attempts to explain what happens, first, the solution:

- Go to your spacemacs config file `SPC f e d` and look for function `dotspacemacs/user-config`
- Add `(setq ns-alternate-modifier nil)` to the function's body, it disables Emacs interpretation of Key `Command`
- Add `(setq ns-command-modifier 'meta)` to the function's body, it remaps Emacs `meta` key to `Control`. I realized later that I needed this remap, as `Command` can't work as `meta` anymore, because the previous setting makes Emacs forget about that key completely
- Reload your config with `SPC f e R`

Theory behind it:

Emacs was consuming key `Command-e` as `M-e` which is bound to `forward-sentence` the solution is then to `(setq ns-alternate-modifier nil)` to stop Emacs from reacting to key `Command` and allowing the OS to bundle `Command-e + {{followingChar}}` as a single keypress later on, delivering this compound keypress a single char to Emacs.

This generates a new problem: How do you call `M-e` now?, this is why `(setq ns-command-modifier 'meta)` is required. In my keyboard configuration this has the effect of making key `Control` `meta` which is incredible handy. so `M-e` is now `Ctrl-e`

Before finding this solution I was barely surviving by invoking `C-x 8 ' a` for a single `á`.

Comment: How you do what? Please elaborate on how this answers the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think you need to mention that other standard macOs apps use alt to produce some non English characters and the emacs binding blocks the normal macOs behaviour. Most users here don't use macOs and so are confused by your answer